# Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvipdfm', (hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode

Tags: packages

I am new to latex. 
I met the problem during compilation.

*Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvipdfm',
(hyperref)  because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode.*

And I searched this website and deleted dvipdfm from \RequirePackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,urlcolor=black,hyperindex,CJKbookmarks,dvipdfm]{hyperref}

then the compiler log shows another error, and said "add dvipdfm may fix this"

so I am confused how to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, it can compile in one computer (with Win7) but not others (win10).

Comment: Hm, which engine do you use to compile? Engine `pdflatex` produced pdfs, `latex` produced dvi and can use `images.esc`...

Comment: if you showed "the other error" someone could probably offer help. Most likely you have another package using `dvipdfm` option when it should not be there.